# Reset iPhone 5 without iCloud password

Tags: iphone, icloud, password

First of all: No I didn't get the phone off of someone else and no I can't get the password by going to iforgot.apple.com (because the email address used for the account has been deleted, so emailing doesn't work)

The iPhone is currently in the state where it acts like you just got it (because I tried to reset the phone by typing the wrong passcode 10 times), but after going through a few steps it will ask for the iCloud username and password. I don't care about any of the data on it, I just need to delete everything off it, so I can actually do something with it.

Comment: If findmyiphone is still turned on you will not be able to get around this, by design.   If you haven't already try iforgot.apple.com because receiving an email is not the only password reset mechanism offered there.  You may have set some secret questions and forgotten.

Answer (score -2):

Well if data on your iCloud account is not important to you, you can just simply create a new account and use it for your phone.

Just make sure you keep that email address this time! :)

Comment: You won't be able to logout without a current icloud's password. Don't misinform people.